# Increment field in Doctrine ODM mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I've added as the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#increment) states : the follwing annotation:

```
/** Increment */
```

then I generated the documents, but I couldn't find the function that will increment my field as the documentation stated! 
Could you help please here?

Answer (score 0):

You need the @ in front of Increment:

```
/** @Increment */
```

Comment: if I do so , I have this error :
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@increment" in property ng\NearBundle\Do
  cument\Users::$ads_number was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a
   "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: As you can read you; are missing the following 'use' statement: `use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Increment`